Confused about the Lewis dot structure of SO2 and SeO3
I am trying to relearn topics in General Chemistry including Lewis structures and formal charge, but I feel like my logic is not logic-ing.
I am confused as to why the correct structure of $\ce{SeO3}$ is as follows:
I thought to achieve the lowest formal charge for all the atoms, in the molecule, it would make more sense if Se was double bonded to each of the oxygens. Then the formal charge of the oxygens and selenium would all equal zero. Also I thought that selenium is one of the atoms that does not follow the octet rule.
I have the same question about $\ce{SO2}$ (please ignore the dipole sign there).

Basically I am confused when drawing Lewis structures, shouldn't the "correct" structure have the lowest formal charge on all atoms?
